# C++ Knowing the type of Derived ptr after retrieving from a Base container

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance

I'm trying to implement some new capabilities to already existing codes. The existing codes contain a pure abstract class with a decode and encode method for message parsing/mapping. A Handler class inherit from this message interface, as well as from a class (let's call this Fields) that contains all the fields to be mapped. The Handler class only contains the definitions for the virtual methods from the interface. Inside the definition is where a mapping class (call it Mapping) that have all the logic for mapping the fields in the Fields class is called. This forms a Message.

```
class Interface
{
  virtual void Decode(char * buf, int len);
  virtual void Encode(char * buf, int len);
}

class Fields
{
  type1 field1;
  type2 field2;
}

class Mapping : public Mapping_Rules
{
  // Rules for mapping field1
  // Rules for mapping field2

  static int len = sizeof(type1) + sizeof(type2); // Redacted codes

  void Read()  { // Perform mapping from char buf to class structure }
  void Write() { // Perform mapping from class structure to char buf }
}

class Handler : public Fields, public Interface
{
  void Decode(char * buf, int len)
  {
    // Do stuff
    Mapping obj;
    obj.Read();
  }

  void Encode(char * buf, int len)
  {
    // Do stuff
    Mapping obj;
    obj.Write();
  }
}
```

There are several of these Messages, and what I want to do is create a generic container to store different types of Messages. I created my own Base interface that the Fields class can inherit from, and store the Handlers pointers (which inherit from Fields which inherit from the Base interface) after casting them to the Base pointers. So I ran into a problem with this, which is when I retrieve the pointer from the container, I don't know which type it originally was. This is a problem for me because the decode and encode methods that I mentioned before requires a length, which is unique to each message. So I need to know the type to pass in the correct length.

```
class My_Own_Interface { virtual ~My_Own_Interface(); }

class Fields : pubic My_Own_Interface {}

// Somewhere in the code
Handler * handler;
My_Own_Interface * container[5];
container[i] = static_cast<My_Own_Interface *>(handler));

item = container[i]; // Item is wondering what type he/she is because his/her creator
                        // is so bad at OOP design
// End
```

To resolve this, I'm trying to perform dynamic_cast<> on the container's item to see which Derived type it was.

```
if (dynamic_cast<Handler *>(item)) { // Do stuff }
```

Of course this works, but I read that it was not good design to re-cast the Base ptr back to the Derived ptr. So I was wondering, how can I design my container stuff to have good OOP design/structure without changing or changing too much of the original codes? I apologize ahead of time for showing bad designing on my part.

Comment: You cannot do `container.push_back` if `container` is a `My_Own_Interface*` pointer.

Comment: Add a virtual `GetLength` function, and/or make `Read` and `Write` virtual?

Comment: @aschepler Sorry, it's kinda abstracted code. I fixed it to make it more accurate.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm I did try the virtual GetLength function, but I got an error from the compiler saying "request for member GetLength in item, which is of a non-class type My_Own_Interface*". I didn't know what that means exactly.

Comment: @ThomasPhan That particular compiler error just means you used `.` where you should have used `->`.

Comment: Oh......wow I guess that way would have worked then. But then, is the way I'm doing this correct? If you guys have any suggestion of how I could make this design better and put it as an answer, I'll happily accept it, since mainly I'm looking for advice on OOP designs.

Comment: @ThomasPhan Use of `dynamic_cast` is fine, casting safely across inheritance hierarchy is its purpose. [dynamic_cast conversion](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast)